# Why does iteratively generating nested lists not delete the inner list

Tags: python, list, scope

```
my_list = ['abc', 'def']

outer_list = []
for element in my_list:
    inner_list = []
    for ch in element:
        inner_list.append(ch)
    outer_list.append(inner_list)
print(outer_list)
# output [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

My question is, why does this work? i.e., why does the, `line inner_list = []`, not obliterate prior instances of inner_list?  I think it has to do with the scope of outer_list being outside of the 'for' block. Perhaps once inner_list takes up residence there it is detached from the variable name? Is that close?

Comment: Because variable != object. A variable holds a reference. If the reference changes, doesn't necessarily mean the object is destroyed.

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you run `inner_list=[]` it just makes the variable point to another address in the memory. `outer_list` still points to the old memory address (previous `inner_list`). While there is a pointer to it, it will not be freed.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to consider these 2 cases with full explanation in comments:

1. Case with `list = []`:

   ```
   my1stList = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5]  # my1stList references  the list [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5]
   my2ndList = my1stList        # my2ndList references the same list as my1stList
   my1stList = []               # my1stList references another list (which is empty)
   print(my2ndList)             # it prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ```
2. Case with `list[:] = []`:

   ```
   my1stList = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5]  # my1stList references the list [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5]
   my2ndList = my1stList        # my2ndList references the same list as my1stList
   my1stList[:] = []            # the list referenced by my1stList is emptied
   print(my2ndList)             # it prints: []
   ```

I hope it is now understood for you: each list you append into `outer_list` is never overwritten. Only its previous reference `inner_list` changes.